# Subversion set up to use Windows Authentication but still asking for user / pass

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I've set up SVN on a server (called 'dev') which is on our domain
I used VisualSVN Server to do this....

I've set it up to use windows auth. I added my domain user to the allowed (Read/Write) list
I created a repository, copied the url, and took a check out on my client machine.
It still asks me for a username / password.... which obviously, it shouldn't.

Any ideas what i may of set up wrong?

If i enter my domain user name and password in the box that pops up, it works...
however it should send this automatically??

Comment: Simple question: Where are you accessing from? (A windows host in the same domain?)

Comment: yes, windows host, same domain

Comment: can you give details about how you configure SVN Apache?

Comment: Any particular client you're using? or are you browsing to it through a web browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, SVN prompts for authentication whenever required. Meaning when it hass not "cached" your user credentials, when you have changed passwords, when your password has expired and so forth are some of the sample situations.

Once you type in the password and ask SVN to save authentication for you, it wont prompt again, but if you happen to access in some of the special situations as described above, it is quite normal to get a prompt.